# Can't upgrade from 16.05 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, permissions, updates

So for more clarification from the last post i will redo it; Ok, so i used crouton to install Ubuntu 16.04 with gnome, and its nice, but little applications actually work...

I first tried the update manager, and it said it didn't have permissions to update, so i tried the  `do-release-upgrade` commands in the terminal, and heres what popped up.

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,251 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,252 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'
sudo: unable to execute /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-ky8ganal/bionic: Permission denied
Hangup
```

Can anyone help? I didnt give enough clarification on the last post so sorry about that...

Comment: Omg i am not used to the formatting on this website, so i think i typed in the code section, my mistake

Comment: You may edit your post by clicking on the word **[Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1458453/edit)** below your question. Crouton based instructions are off topic here as that is not how official Ubuntu is installed.

Comment: Why don't you edit your first question and put all the information there?